# PHP displaying only brands that match the category that is chosen

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables one is "brands" and the other "products" this is how they are setup:

Brands

id | name | .
................
1  | nike   | .
2  | puma  | .
3  | reebok| .

Products

id | name    | cat  | brand_id | .
.........................................
1  | item1   | 3    | 1 .
2  | item2   | 3    | 1 .
3  | item3   | 2    | 2 .
4  | item4   | 3    | 3 .
5  | item5   | 3    | 3 .

So lets say someone clicks on a category which has an id of 3
then my page will display all products that have the category id of 3.
What I want to achieve now is to display a list of brands but only those that are linked to the category id of 3 which in this case is nike and reebok this is what I have so far:

```
public function getBrands() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM brands";
        return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
    }
```

and this gets me all my brands perfectly. Then I take all the brand ids like this:

```
// Brand ID Search
$product_brand_ids = [];
foreach($rows as $row) { // $rows get all my products with the category of 3
    $product_brand_ids[] = $row['brand_id'];// 1,1,3,3
}
$brand_ids[] = $product_brand_ids;
```

and then I send them to this method to try and call only the brand ids that I need. Now i try this:

```
public function getBrandsByCats(array $brand_ids) {
    if(!empty($brand_ids)) {
        foreach ($brand_ids as $value) {
            $id = array_unique($value);//removing the duplicates
            $bb = "SELECT * FROM brands WHERE id = ".$id." ";
            return $bb;
        }
    }
}
```

but this gives me an error and says that the query fails because instead of searching for ids one by one it is searching ids like an array like this:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE id = 1 3
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this issue and continue coding?

Comment: how are you searching products by brands? as you mentioned this "$rows get all my products with the category of 3" what value are you getting in $row??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, using inner join will solve your problem. However your brand_id must be foreign key referencing brand id

```
select distinct b.name from product p inner join brand b on p.brand_id=b.id where p.cat=3
```

this is the output of above query

```
nike
reebook
```

You have to pass id instead of 3 for further use

Comment: Hello friend, thank you for replying, I have been trying your solution but I cannot seem to get it to work. I might be typing things incorrectly could you please edit your example and maybe show the exact query that I should be trying using the provided table names and everything. Thank you and I look forward to your reply.